# Migrating Database to new server when there are many references in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

At work we are trying to upgrade infrastructure and finally separate app servers and database servers.  We would like to migrate our current SQL server DBs to a new database server, but we have *many* Excel spreadsheets around the office that have database connections and data sources that link to our current db server.

Finding all of those references would be a fairly monumental task.  Is there any way to re-route all of these data sources without having to find and update each Excel file that is out there?  We're not even sure that all of these use consistent drivers, some may be ODBC, a lot are definitely OLE, some may even use ADO.Net through Excel Macros.

Does anybody out there have experience with a situation like this?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let that be a lesson not to use excel as a database front end :) but to answer your question, you _might_ be able to use a DNS alias if the old server is being taken offline.

Comment: This is at an investment firm.  Excel is a religion.  Thanks for the answer, but I'm wondering if DNS covers all type of SQL server connections.  :-)

Comment: The connection to the SQL server would be using NetBIOS machine name, TCPIP address or a url. Can't you make them to be the same as the old server's?

Comment: You can use Excel, you just need a layer between it and the DB.  Trust me, I've worked at several financial companies and experienced this pain many times.

Comment: DNS should cover the majority but it may not catch all.  If there are no standards around how connections were defined then you are likely going to have outliers that you have to deal with manually.

Comment: It could be a good moment to introduce formal administration of connections, design naming schemes for departments and application areas, etc.

Comment: You can also use Aliases in SQL Server Configuration Manager. It will redirect SQL connection only but this is applied to the client. If you can broadcast the registry keys to all affected workstations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the connection to the SQL Server in the excel spreadsheets made by DNS name and not IP, then the following procedure will do the work:

1. Setup the new server with a new host name, a new DNS record , like there's a standard new installation.
2. Move your data & configuration to the new server. remember to move logins and make sure they mapped correctly.
3. Change the name of the old server. Make sure the old name is not referenced by the DNS anymore.
4. Add new DNS record (A record) to your DNS server, referencing to the IP of the new server. (BTW, you can also use WINS/SQL Alias, and not the DNS server way)
5. Now, the old name is referenced to the new server IP. BUT, connections won't work in AD environment because of the Kerberos protocol. to make it work, assuming the server's new name is newname.ADDomain.com, and the service account of SQL Server is ADDomain\sqlsvc, run the following command on the SQL server: `SetSPN -S MSSQLSVC/newname.ADDomain.com:1433 ADDomain\sqlsvc`. if you're not in domain environment or not using windows authenticaiton you can skip this step.

After you done, clients will be able to connect the new server with the old name. I suggest that before doing this procedure you'll make sure you know how to do it and how to roll-back in case it's needed (which means, making sure you know how to get the old server up and running with the old name).

If you want to be on the safe side, and ready for future changes, you should consider making a little change: instead of using the old name as an alias to the new server, set up AlwaysOn cluster, and use this old name as the name of the listener, and not the name of the new DB server itself.

this way, future moves will be easier, as the clients will always use the listener name to connect and AlwaysOn will route them to the active server.

Hope this helps.